# jquery get request not working sometimes on server. But when same code execute on localhost it works fine

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, cpanel

I am inserting an item into the cart through getting request, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't on `the server` but works properly on `localhost`.

jquery code

```
$.get("/cart/"+ id ,function(data){
    $('#quantity').html(data);
});
```

This url hit controller method called store

```
public function store(Request $request, $item_id) {

    $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

    $cart->add($item_id);

    request()->session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart')->totalQty : null;

}
```

and here is cart class

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Cart {

public $items = null;
public $totalQty = 0;

public function __construct($oldCart) {
    if ($oldCart) {
        $this->items = $oldCart->items;
        $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
    }
}

public function add($id) {
    $storedItem = ['qty' => 0, 'item' => $id];

    if ($this->items) {
        if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
            $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
        }
    }

    $storedItem['qty']++;

    //an item is added to cart along with some details
    $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
    $this->totalQty++;

}

public function removeItem($id) {

    $this->totalQty -= $this->items[$id]['qty'];
    unset($this->items[$id]);
}

}
```

Comment: Description is to short write with code and case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Any chance your local environment has a different spec than your server - I.e. different php version, which would cause code that receives request to fail?

Comment: i have been searching for the solution  since 2 days still no luck

Comment: no, both have same php version

Comment: what is `id` in jquery code? and what is the driving using for session, `file`, `database` or .. ?

Comment: For sure, the answer lies on your Developer Tools/Web Inspector. Open it and send us a screenshot.